# Purge all messages in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have several ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 clusters setup to replicate between data centres with [mirroring](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html#mirror).

Our previous failover had been an emergency, and it's likely the state had fallen out of sync. When we next performed our scheduled failover tests weeks-old messages were sent to the consumers. I know that mirroring is asynchronous so it is expected that synchronization may not be 100% all the time. However, these messages were not within the time frame of synchronization delays. It is worth noting that we've had several events which I expect might throw mirroring off. We had hit the [NFS split brain](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3030) issue as well as the past emergency fail over

As such, we are looking for a way to purge (or sync) all messages on the standby server after we know that there have been problems with the mirroring to prevent a similar scenario from happening. There are over 5,000 queues, so preferably the operation doesn't need to be run on a queue by queue basis.

Is there any way to accomplish this, either in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 or a later version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no programmatic way to simply delete all the data from every queue on the broker. However, you can combine a few management operations (e.g. in a script) to get the same result. You can use the [`getQueueNames`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#getQueueNames--) method to get the name of every queue and then pass those names to the [`destroyQueue(String)`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html#destroyQueue-java.lang.String-) method.

However, the simplest way to clear all the data would probably be to simply stop the broker, clear the data directory, and then restart the broker.